# How to calculated decimal values in vba access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to update an inventory stock as follows:

```
[InventoryStock] = ([CurrentInventoryStock]-[QuantityOrdered])
```

Note that `QuantityOrdered` can be decimal, something like: 5.2 or can be full number, something like 8.

- The `InventoryStock` column is set to Number (double)
- The `QuantityOrdered` column is also set to Number (double)

When `QuantityOrdered` is a full number, like 5, it works perfectly; but when `QuantityOrdered` is a decimal number, like 7.5 , then I receive:

> Run-time error 3144 (syntax error in update statement)

...highlighting the update code that I wrote in VBA.

```
If Not IsNull(Me.QuantityOrdered) Then
    CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE Inventory SET InventoryStock = InventoryStock - " & Nz(Me.QuantityOrdered.Value, 0) & ""
End If
```

As described above, my goal is to deducted the quantity ordered (whether decimal or full number) from the Inventory Stock value.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Also, you should use Currency as the data type as subtracting Doubles often returns results with bit errors.

Comment: Consider a [parameter query](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/use-parameters-to-ask-for-input-when-running-a-query-c2806d3d-d500-45a8-8507-ec6af351b6ed) for your `UPDATE`.  Then the db engine can treat the number as an actual number ... avoiding the problem you encountered when implicitly casting the number to (the wrong) string.

Comment: You may want to consider http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding your problem:**

Using implicit string conversion will use a decimal separator following your country/language settings, for example a (`,`), which causes your issue.

So you should explicitely use `Str()` to convert the numeric value to a string to get a dot (`.`) as separator.

**Two more small remarks:**

- `NZ(…)` is not necessary because you already check that before (`If Not IsNull(Me.QuantityOrdered) Then`).
- Appending just an empty string (`& ""`) is not necessary too.

```vba
If Not IsNull(Me.QuantityOrdered) Then
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Inventory SET InventoryStock = InventoryStock - " & Str(Me.QuantityOrdered.Value)
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works as expected.